# Why am I getting "history.state seems to have been manually replaced" when using "router.push" in Vitest and nav fails?

Tags: vue-router, vue-test-utils, vitest

I have a Vitest like the following

```js
import { createWebHistory, createRouter } from "vue-router";
import Home from "../components/Home.vue";
import Other from "../components/Other.vue";
const routes = [
  { path: '/', component: Home },
  { path:"/other", component: Other}
]
const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(),
  routes,
})
export {router as mainRoutes};
```

```html
<template>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="links">
      <router-link to="/">Go to Home</router-link>
      <router-link class="other" to="/Other">Go to elsewhere</router-link>
    </div>
    <router-view></router-view>
  </div>


</template>
<script setup>
</script>
<style scoped>
.links{
  display:flex;
}
.wrapper{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
</style>
```

```js
import { describe, it, beforeAll } from 'vitest';
import { mount } from '@vue/test-utils';
import {mainRoutes} from "../src/router/index.mjs";
import App from "../src/App.vue";

describe("App", ()=>{
  expect(App).toBeTruthy()
  let wrapper;
  beforeAll(async ()=>{
    await mainRoutes.push('/')
    await mainRoutes.isReady()
    wrapper = mount(App, {
      global: {
        plugins: [mainRoutes]
      }
    });
  })
  it("Simple Click Test", async ()=>{
    await wrapper.find('.other').trigger('click');
    console.log(wrapper.html());
    expect(wrapper.html()).toContain('I Think you should be somewhere else');
  })
})
```

But when I run with `vitest run --coverage` I get...

```
[Vue Router warn]: history.state seems to have been manually replaced without preserving the necessary values. Make sure to preserve existing history state if you are manually calling history.replaceState:

history.replaceState(history.state, '', url)

You can find more information at https://next.router.vuejs.org/guide/migration/#usage-of-history-state.
```

and the click doesn't seem to work because the test fails and the console log shows the old value.

I also tried adding `await mainRoutes.isReady()` after the click but that didn't help either.

This all does seem to match [the docs](https://test-utils.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/vue-router.html#using-a-real-router)

How do I get a router-link click to update the router-view?

I can confirm that it works this way...

```
// await wrapper.find('.other').trigger('click');
await mainRoutes.push('/other')
await mainRoutes.isReady()
console.log(wrapper.html());
expect(wrapper.html()).toContain('I Think you should be somewhere else');
```

But I still get the warning and can't get it to work with the click

Answer (score 2):

Ok, i figured it out for my case. The solution for me was to use `createMemoryHistory` instead of `createWebHistory` in the tests. Because i am in node environment and not in browser environment. Maybe this is also helpful for you or others